# Android startActivityForResult returns null to onActivityResult when using camera

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am having a problem with startActivityForResult/onActivityResult where data returns null. I use startActivityForResult(camera) and manage to save the image into the device.

This is the piece in the activity that calls the Camera

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upload_new_tire);
    setUpWings();

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new MyCamera(this));
}
```

This is my onActivityResult function

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data){
    Log.i("request, result Code", String.valueOf(requestCode) + " and " + String.valueOf(resultCode));
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
        imageButton.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

This is where I call startActivityForResult and save the image to file.

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,
                    "autosoftpro.reusedtire.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            mContext.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

This is the error message, it happens because 'Intent data' is null. I have tried to look at other posts which are similar but didn't manage to figure out the reason why.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {autosoftpro.reusedtire/autosoftpro.reusedtire.UploadTireActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: You are using different request codes. `REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE` in your onActivityResult, but `REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO` in your request. That being said, you should try adding `if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED)` first to make sure you have a valid response to work with. You also don't need your super call unless you have an explicit reason to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. They're in fact both equal 1, and it did go into the condition loop if I don't include the condition data!=null

Comment: So your data is in fact null (is evident in the error you posted). The only time that should happen is if you cancel your request (which can be caught with the `if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED)` check.

Comment: Ex that, you are explicitly declaring a URI to use, it won't return any data to you in the intent. See CommonsWare's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it happens because 'Intent data' is null

As is explained in [the documentation for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), there are two possibilities:

- You include `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`. In that case, you are not returned anything in the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`, but you already know where the image should be.
- You do not include `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, in which case the `data` extra will be a thumbnail `Bitmap.

You are including `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, which means you should not be checking the `data` extra. Instead, look for the image wherever you specified in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Missed that part prior to my comment, 100% correct. He explicitly declared the URI in the call, just use it :P